# How to search multiple Pattern in grep while ignoring the first pattern if appearing consecutively

Tags: grep

I have an input like below. I want to find out everything starting with `abc` and ending with `mno` including lines in between but if `abc` appears again before `mno` comes, then I want to ignore the first matched `abc`. The idea is, I just need a group which starts with `abc` and ends with `mno` which are nearest to each other.

`test.txt` file contains below data:

```
abc
bbb
abc
yyy
mno
abc
xxx
mno
```

Expected output :

```
abc
yyy
mno
abc
xxx
mno
```

I am using the below `grep` liner:

```
grep -ozP  "(?s)(abc).\*?(mno)" test.txt
```

The result is:

```
abc
bbb
abc
yyy
mno
abc
xxx
mno
```

The first two lines should not be there in the output. Please advise what I can modify in `grep` to get the desired result.

Comment: Does the solution have to use grep? I imagine a solution in perl...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -ozP  "(?s)(abc)[^(abc)]*(mno)" 1
abc
yyy
mno
abc
xxx
mno
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about this is to reverse the file using `tac`, find matches *starting* with `mno` and *ending* with `abc`, and reverse that to get the desired result. I got the following to work:

```
$ tac test.txt | pcregrep -M 'mno(\n|.)*?abc' | tac
abc
yyy
mno
abc
xxx
mno
```

(I'm using `pcregrep` for the multiline `-M` flag)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case perl is an option for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# saved lines to print out
my @out = ();
# should we save lines?
my $saving = 0;
while (<>) {
  if (/abc/) {
    if ($saving) {
      # this is the second /abc/, so dump what we were saving and start over
      @out = ($_);
    } else {
      # this is the first /abc/, so save it and start saving lines
      push @out, $_;
      $saving = 1;
    }
  } elsif (/mno/) {
    if ($saving) {
      # print what we've saved, plus this /mno/ ending line, then reset
      print @out, $_;
      @out=();
      $saving=0;
    }
  } else {
    # otherwise, save lines if we should be
    push @out, $_ if $saving;
  }
}
```